# Issue opening with QGIS3.4 Madeira

Tags: qgis-3, installation, error, dll

I just installed QGIS Madeira 3.4 on my WINDOWS Vista PC (64bits).
But I can't work with it, since I keep getting the same error:

[image]

And just after, this one:

[image]

Should I uninstall it?
What could I do in order to work with QGIS?

Comment: First step: Upgrade to a supported OS.

Comment: Did you start qgis from the start menu? Try to open the OSGeo4W-Shell and run these commands: `py3_env.bat` then `qt5_env.bat` and last `qgis-ltr.bat`. That should the same as starting qgis from the start menu.

Comment: tried the solution presented. Did not work. Guess is the OS that is causing this issue...